# inner join with where clause undesired results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to just get the rows from the two tables that have the matching id, and out of those only the ones with the required username.

I have these tables:

```
threads table:
threadID
title
category
author
date_posted
post
last_reply
last_author
total_posts
isLocked
isSticky
```

```
replies table:
repliedID
threadID
author
date
reply
```

I tried this as my query:

```
$results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT t.author as tauthor,t.category, t.title, t.last_reply, t.threadID, t.isLocked, t.isSticky
                               FROM threads t
                               INNER JOIN replies r 
                               ON (r.author = t.author)
                               WHERE r.author = '$user'");
```

I should be getting 4 results for this query, (number of threads that match the reply id) but i get 36 (the number of replies is 9, but for some reason it is multiplying by the threads 4 to get 36).

I know its something to do with the where clause but i can't get it working so that only the rows that contain the username are selected.

Why is my query not working and what should i do to get the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: Also, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be joining the table on the author column, as it seems that you want to link the tables by the threadID.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    threads as t INNER JOIN replies as r on t.threadID = r.threadID
WHERE
    r.author = 'user';
```